# How can I increase the size of the pie (Chart.JS)?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I'm generating a pie chart with legend that looks like so:

[image]

As you can perceive, the pie is pitifully puny. I prefer it to be twice as tall and twice as wide.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");

    Chart.pluginService.register({
        afterDatasetsDraw: function (chartInstance) {
            var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;

            ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(14, 'bold', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
            ctx.fillStyle = '#666';

            chartInstance.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {

                for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                    var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model,
                        total = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].total,
                        mid_radius = model.innerRadius + (model.outerRadius - model.innerRadius) / 2,
                        start_angle = model.startAngle,
                        end_angle = model.endAngle,
                        mid_angle = start_angle + (end_angle - start_angle) / 2;

                    var x = mid_radius * 1.5 * Math.cos(mid_angle);
                    var y = mid_radius * 1.5 * Math.sin(mid_angle);

                    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
                    if (i === 0 || i === 3 || i === 7) { // Darker text color for lighter background
                        ctx.fillStyle = '#666';
                    }
                    var percent = String(Math.round(dataset.data[i] / total * 100)) + "%";
                    // this prints the data number
                    // this prints the percentage
                    ctx.fillText(percent, model.x + x, model.y + y);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    var data = {
        labels: [
            "Bananas (18%)",
            "Lettuce, Romaine (14%)",
            "Melons, Watermelon (10%)",
            "Pineapple (10%)",
            "Berries (10%)",
            "Lettuce, Spring Mix (9%)",
            "Broccoli (8%)",
            "Melons, Honeydew (7%)",
            "Grapes (7%)",
            "Melons, Cantaloupe (7%)"
        ],
        datasets: [
        {
            data: [2755, 2256, 1637, 1608, 1603, 1433, 1207, 1076, 1056, 1048],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FFE135",
                "#3B5323",
                "#fc6c85",
                "#ffec89",
                "#021c3d",
                "#3B5323",
                "#046b00",
                "#cef45a",
                "#421C52",
                "#FEA620"
                  ]
        }]
    };

    var optionsPie = {
        responsive: true,
        scaleBeginAtZero: true,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    return data.labels[tooltipItem.index] + ": " +
                        formatter.format(data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index]);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var ctx = $("#top10ItemsChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var top10PieChart = new Chart(ctx,
    {
        type: 'pie',
        data: data,
        options: optionsPie,
        animation: {
            duration: 0,
            easing: "easeOutQuart",
            onComplete: function () {
                var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                        var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model,
                        total = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].total,
                        mid_radius = model.innerRadius + (model.outerRadius - model.innerRadius) / 2,
                        start_angle = model.startAngle,
                        end_angle = model.endAngle,
                        mid_angle = start_angle + (end_angle - start_angle) / 2;

                        var x = mid_radius * Math.cos(mid_angle);
                        var y = mid_radius * Math.sin(mid_angle);

                        ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
                        if (i === 3) { // Darker text color for lighter background
                            ctx.fillStyle = '#444';
                    }
                    var percent = String(Math.round(dataset.data[i] / total * 100)) + "%";
                    // this prints the data number
                    ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x + x, model.y + y);
                    // this prints the percentage
                    ctx.fillText(percent, model.x + x, model.y + y + 15);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

    $("#top10Legend").html(top10PieChart.generateLegend());
```

How can I increase the size of the pie?

### UPDATE

The "View" as requested by Nkosi is:

```
<div class="row" id="top10Items">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="topleft">
            <h2 class="sectiontext">Top 10 Items</h2>
            <br />
            <div id="piechartlegendleft">
                <div id="container">
                    <canvas id="top10ItemsChart"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div id="top10Legend" class="pieLegend"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    . . .
```

The classes "row" and "col-md-6" are Bootstrap classes.

The custom classes are "topleft":

```
.topleft {
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

...sectionText:

```
.sectiontext {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
    color: green;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
```

...and "pieLegend":

```
.pieLegend li span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You just need to change the canvas size.

When you are creating the chart you can specify it right in the element:

`<canvas id="top10ItemsChart" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>`

Or if you prefer to do it in javascript

```
var ctx = $("#top10ItemsChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
ctx.width = 1000;
ctx.height = 1000;
```

If the resizing doesn't work as you wish, you can also try setting the `maintainAspectRatio` option to false:

```
var optionsPie = {
    /** ... */
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    /** ... */
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That overflows the bottom boundary; changing the values from 1000 to 800 makes no difference. Actually, it's not that it's too large, but that it's pushed too far to the bottom. I'll try adjusting the top margin to a negative valule...

Comment: Your answer plus the following works wonders:
#top10ItemsChart {
            margin-top: -32px;
        }

Comment: the "maintainAspectRatio: false" made it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Set aspectRatio: 3 in the options, it will make it small too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, rather different but for associated querents, I wanted my pie chart to not be as large but still allow the legend to be long across the top.

```
myChart = new Chart("myChart", {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
  labels: [],
  datasets: [{
    data: [],
    backgroundColor: []
  }]
},
options: {
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: "Expense Categories"
  },
  aspectRatio:2.5
}
});
```

Setting the canvas aspect ratio to 2.5 to allow it to be wide but not tall did the trick for me!